# SparseCategoricalCrosstentropy vs sparse_categorical_crossentropy

Tags: keras, tensorflow, loss-function

What is the difference between SparseCategoricalCrosstentropy and sparse_categorical_crossentropy ?

[SparseCategoricalCrossentropy](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/SparseCategoricalCrossentropy): Computes the crossentropy loss between the labels and predictions.

[sparse_categorical_crossentropy](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/sparse_categorical_crossentropy): Computes the sparse categorical crossentropy loss.

But I am still not sure. Any loss will always be calculates between labels and predictions. SO how are these two different ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SparseCategoricalCrossentropy is a class. So you have to define a object first then you can compute the loss using it.

```
scce = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy()
scce(y_true, y_pred).numpy()
```

While sparse_categorical_crossentropy is merely a function which can be directly used to compute cost.

```
loss = tf.keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)
```

If you are to pass the loss to a Sequential API then you must pass the object ,not the function.

```
model.compile('sgd', loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy())
```

Comment: so value of
`scce(y_true, y_pred).numpy()` should be equal to `tf.keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)`,
right ?

Comment: yes it will be same

Answer (score 0):

SparseCategoricalCrossentropy is a class while sparse_categorical_crossentropy is a function.

SparseCategoricalCrossentropy -> You create an instance of this class and then pass the true values and predicted values.

sparse_categorical_crossentropy -> You pass the true and predicted values just as you would do with any other function.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the difference between being function and class, the instance from `tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy` allows to be invoked with argument [`sample_weight`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/SparseCategoricalCrossentropy#__call__). It would be rather convenient if you need to assign samples with different weights. More details can be found https://keras.io/api/losses/#standalone-usage-of-losses.